# Writing a hex escaped char in Powershell

Tags: powershell-3.0

Is there any way to write something like this in Powershell? (Linux would be with Perl)

```
char foo = '\x41';
```

I need to input some non-printable characters to one of my programs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’d like to offer a different approach than casting as hex.  Instead of using hex, PowerShell 7 supports Unicode character encoding (see article [about_special_characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7#unicode-character-ux) > Unicode characters).  So, with x041 as Latin capital A, the Unicode equivalent would be `` "`u{41}" ``. The Microsoft docs example demonstrated with this example: `` "`u{2195}" `` (note the backtick precedes the letter).

Comment: Just a nitpick - `{41}` is still "using hex". i.e. 41 is hex for decimal 65 (A). So I guess this answer isn't instead of using hex, it's just using hex a different way.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by **casting an int to char**.

With a decimal number :

```
 $foo = (65 -as [char])
```

And from hexa :

```
 $foo = (0x41 -as [char])
```

Both will set `$foo` to `A`

Answer (score 0):

Short form is:

```
$foo = [char]0x41
```