# Add Hex Chars directly to a string in PowerShell

Tags: hex, powershell-3.0

I want to do something like this (I tried four different ways).  Create a string value that contains hex characters:

```bsh
$searchString = "filterValue\xEF\xBF\xBD"
#$searchString = "filterValue" + 0xEF -as [char] + 0xBF -as [char] + 0xBD -as [char]
#$searchString = "filterValue" + 0xEF + 0xBF + 0xBD
$searchString = "filterValue\0xEF\0xBF\0xBD"
Write-Host "$searchString len=$($searchString.Length)"
```

Length should be 14.

Is there someone to add them inline rather than creating three separate char values as shown in this post: [Writing a hex escaped char in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626455/writing-a-hex-escaped-char-in-powershell)

I tried the longer way:

```bsh
$char1 = (0xEF -as [char])
$char2 = (0xBF -as [char])
$char3 = (0xBD -as [char])
$searchString = "filterValue" + $char1 + $char2 + $char3
Write-Host "$searchString len=$($searchString.Length)"
$posSearchString = $filterBytes.IndexOf("$searchString")
```

But that doesn't seem to match what I'm looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use subexpressions:

```
$searchString = "filterValue$([char]0xEF)$([char]0xBF)$([char]0xBD)"
```

String concatenation or using the format operator would work too as long as you cast the values:

```
$searchString = "filterValue" + [char]0xEF + [char]0xBF + [char]0xBD
$searchString = "filterValue{0}{1}{2}" -f [char]0xEF, [char]0xBF, [char]0xBD
```

If you want to use the `-as` operator instead of casting the numbers to chars you need to group the expressions:

```
$searchString = "filterValue" + (0xEF -as [char]) + (0xBF -as [char]) + (0xBD -as [char])
$searchString = "filterValue{0}{1}{2}" -f (0xEF -as [char]), (0xBF -as [char]), (0xBD -as [char])
```